# Laptop not starting up after cleaning cpu fan

Tags: laptop, power-supply

I have Acer Aspire 5745G Laptop its fan started making noise. So i followed up this [tutorial](http://www.insidemylaptop.com/disassemble-acer-aspire-5745-laptop/). And cleaned Fan and put everything back up.

But now when connecting battery automatically starts up laptop and it auto shutdown in 1-3 seconds. Pressing power button doesn't do anything.

**Here how i put it back on.**

On first attempt i put everything back except DVD ROM

On Second attempt i didn't connect my HDD

On third attempt i just connected basic things.(see pictures)

Cpu fan
Dc charger port
Video cable(Laptop screen)
Webcam
Power button
TouchPad
Dvd Rom eject button

> Motherboard with fan connection only

[image]

> Screen & webcam wire connected

[image]

> Power, DVD Eject button , touchpad wire connected

[image]

And finally connected DC Power jack wire and wifi anntena

[image]

**I didn't remove RAM & bios battery.**

In third attempt laptop didn't started automatically when connecting battery. But power button still not works.

Comment: There's not enough information and this will most likely be closed. What model laptop? What were the steps you took? etc.

Comment: Using only your link as a reference, This system requires a lot of teardown to get to the fan... I would check the memory modules are seated properly first, then the remaining connections paying particular attention to the keyboard connections and top frame (where the power button is located).

Comment: @acejavelin i didn't removed ram.

Comment: does fan spin now? if not it will be shut down by thermoprotection. On last image white wire to your wifi seems to be touching chassis. try w/o it. Check voltage on DC jack if you have tools to see if power is supplied to mobo.

Comment: @fixer1234 thanx... i have seprated q&A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You best option is to start again.  Your laptop is hopefully detecting something is wrong and shutting down as a safety measure.  It could be as simple as your CPU fan is not connected.  I doubt after 3 seconds you're reaching a shutdown temperature, which could be the other option.

Most likely if you've forget to reconnect something, or something is connected the wrong way around, but check your CPU cooler and fan carefully.

Good luck.

Comment: I checked fan is connected fine. updated question with more details. On third attempt my laptop didn't auto started.

Comment: I can't see from the photos, but double check you've got all the white connectors the right way around and that they are pushed home fully.  The inserts can get pushed back sometimes, so make sure these are still in the plugs properly - i.e.: Check each wire on those white connectors to make sure the metal tags are in fully and the socket itself is in fully.

Comment: Really the same goes for those ribbon connectors.  Pull the white lock bar back, push in the ribbon then push the locking bar back in place.  Sorry if these are obvious instructions but just trying to think of everything.

Comment: Another try - ensure the fan can move (by hand).  If it can't, because a wire is trapped, then the cpu could shutdown as a safety measure.

Comment: Fan is not trapped its easily movable by hand. Which ribbon connectors are you talking about?

Comment: Any ribbon you've removed.  Just make sure they are seated correctly again.  Looking at your photos, it looks like the locking bar is black and you lift it before inserting the cable, then click it down again.  In your 3rd photo I can see 3 that are connected and at least 1 that isn't.

Comment: Found the issue. 
Power button wire connection pin was damaged and it was causing short circuit making laptop automatically start and shutdown.

Answer (score 3):

Found the issue. 
Power button wire connection pin was damaged and it was causing short circuit making laptop automatically start and shutdown.

> Cable damaged pins

[image]